# Which droid lost a part that was discovered by Davin Felth on Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars, droids

In *Star Wars: A New Hope*, after locating the crashed escape pod on Tatooine, a small Imperial troop investigates the place where Davin Felth finds a piece of equipment that he [so famously] addresses: "***Look sir, Droids!***"

[image]
 <sub>*Star Wars: A New Hope*; click to enlarge</sub>

As to how he concluded that it was piece of droid equipment is debatable with [inconsistencies](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Davin_Felth/Legends#Inconsistencies) as well. However this deduction by Davin led the troopers to find Owen and Beru Lars' place (after tracking the Jawas and killing all of them).

As only R2-D2 and C-3PO were the only passengers of the escape pod, the piece found by Davin certainly belonged to one of them. But is it mentioned anywhere exactly which droid did it actually belong to?

Comment: Huh.  I always figured he just noticed some tracks in the sand.  Depending on how packed it is, R2 would leave some pretty obviously droid-like tracks (while 3PO's might be mistaken for a human).

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Wind could easily eliminate all tracks from the sand.

Comment: "Davin" is a legends character, and there is no canonical explanation of who or what the piece fell off of.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Legends short story *When the Desert Wind Turns: The Stormtrooper's Tale* from *Tales From the Mos Eisley Cantina* about Davin Felth identifies that it belonged to an "R2 unit". As such it would appear the part was R2-D2's.

> Davin fished a mechanism from inside the escape pod. There was only one thing that used such a device —an R2 unit. He held it up so all could see. “Look, sir, droids!”
>
> <sub>*When the Desert Wind Turns: The Stormtrooper's Tale*</sub>

Answer (score -2):

Funny, I remember in the novelization of episode IV that it was a ring from one of threepio's Knee joints. Must've been de-canonized in the later years of the EU.

Comment: Hi Aaron, welcome to the site! You may want to take the [tour].